# Unable to overwrite a Column Value using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm planning to overwrite a Field value using pandas but that does not seem to work. Am i missing anything as part of the code below?

```
`for row_no in range(df.shape[0]):
    rowIndex = df.index[row_no]
    if re.search('Fex|Process|PIP|VIP|Generic|Mobility', df.loc[rowIndex].VPC_Sub_Cat, re.I):
        print(df.loc[rowIndex].Headline)
        print(df.loc[rowIndex].VPC_Sub_Cat)
        
        print(df.loc[rowIndex].Final_Result)
        df.loc[rowIndex].Final_Result = 0
        print(df.loc[rowIndex].Final_Result)
        break`
```

The output that I get after running this piece of code is:

```
This is the description of the issue...
VPC-Generic
1
1
```

Also can i achieve the same thing using a function and applying that on a data frame? kindly let me know.

Comment: did you try `df.loc[rowIndex, 'Final_Result'] = 0`?

Comment: Great, I'll try to give some explainations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.loc[rowIndex].Final_Result` is equals to (in most situation though...)

`df.loc[rowIndex]['Final_Result']`

This will cause a chained assignment (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) #Warning)

> Whether a copy or a reference is returned for a setting operation, may depend on the context. This is sometimes called chained assignment and should be avoided. See Returning a View versus Copy.

And then from [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

> But it turns out that **assigning to the product of chained indexing has inherently unpredictable results**.

So using `df.loc[rowIndex, 'Final_Result']` to make sure that the value you assigned is view, not copy.